# creating an account lockout system with j_security_check

Tags: j-security-check

Hi friends i would like to create an account lockout system with form based authentication.

currently i am using j_security check which will get my j_username and j_password from the jsp page and compare with the database, which will redirect me to different jsp pages depending on success or failure.

in addition, i would like to create an extra field FAIL_COUNT in one of the tables in the database to keep check of the number of failures and then to lock the account when it exceeds a certain number of tries.

However, i cannot seem to access the particular table without successful login. Apparently when i have not logged in, i am unable to access and edit the data in the database since the database is being protected.

is there any way i can do an account lockout with j_Security_Check?

thanks